# Compilation error when using empty list initialization constructor in C++17

Tags: c++, c++17, list-initialization

I ran into a weird problem when trying to move to C++17. The problem is that something (and I'm not sure what) changed in C++17 that made list-initialization work differently in the case of a default constructor. I tried to search https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization for more info, but I didn't find anything that looks relevant.

Does someone know the reason the code below compiles in C++14 but not in C++17 when calling `B{}` instead of `B()`?
(I tried it in both gcc 8.2 and 7.3 and icc 19)

```
struct A{
protected:
    A() {}
};

struct B : public A {};


B f(){
    return B(); //compilation OK
    //return B{}; //compilation error
}
```

Comment: Try adding this flag: `-std=c++0x`. I am not sure though.

Comment: @DimChtz That changes the standard to C++11 draft, on compilers old enough to support its pre-standardisation name. Probably not helpful.

Comment: What are you expecting A to be?  Doesn't look valid to me.  {} is an initializer or scope wrapper, () is use to wrap parameters and parentheses.  In your case A() is a constructor with nothing to initialise.  Your compilation error is correct, return B() returns an object with nothing in it, whilst calling the empty constructor first.

Comment: @SPlatten `A` is a type and `B` inherits it. The question is why different methods of creating a `B` fail in different versions of the language.

Comment: In older versions of C, structs and classes were quite different, in modern compilers you can now do a lot more in a struct than previously possible.

Comment: Note that this resolves the issue: `struct B : public A { B() : A() { } };`. Though I don't know why the case with parentheses compiles.

Comment: This works but adding `B() = default;` does not :(

Comment: @SPlatten C has never had classes. In C++, the keyword `struct` has always introduced a class.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I know that I realise C didn't have classes.  structs and classes were different in that classes introduce storage access specifiers, private, protected and public, also inheritance and overloading.  C was never an OO language.

Comment: @SPlatten But structs and classes can't be different in C if C doesn't have classes! And they were never different in C++. So I'm afraid I can't quite figure out what you're saying :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I'm saying that when C++ first appeared back in the 80's structures in C++ didn't have constructors, this came in a later revision.

Comment: @SPlatten Nah. Constructor was part of C++ before C++ was called C++. See Bjarne's [A History of C++: 1979-1991](http://www.stroustrup.com/hopl2.pdf).

Comment: @SPlatten C++'s first real version, in 1985, killed the distinction between classes and structs. Read the CFront Release 1.0 notes [here](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/c_plus_plus/cfront/release_1.0/doc/ReleaseNotes-Lifeboat.pdf). It is true that its developmental precursor, Release E (which was given to universities in 1984) hadn't put this in place yet. Certainly, ISO Standard C++ has always behaved this way.

Comment: @cpplearner, I can't see any mention in your link of structures getting constructors.

Comment: @SPlatten See my link, page 11

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, My experience of using C goes back to the 80's and I jumped onto C++ when it became popular, I don't remember structures with contructors back then, I accept I'm probably wrong.

Comment: @SPlatten Don't worry, you're not alone - almost forty years later many professional C++ developers _still_ don't realise that things defined with the keyword `struct` can have constructors, member functions, access control, bases, ...  (and, more reasonably, many of us still try to avoid it for purely aesthetic reasons). It must be the language's best-kept secret, but it has been so for a very, very long time. Anyway, going back to your initial comment, point is, there's nothing mystical or strange or invalid about the OP's type `A` here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, although I use C++ every day in my day to day role, I prefer Java as an OO language.

Comment: @SPlatten Well, C++ isn't an OO language, so that's reasonable :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I agree, just C with additives :)

Comment: @SPlatten Bjarne may originally have called it "C With Classes", and implied that this makes it OO, but he was wrong. Okay, I'll be charitable and change that to say that the generally-accepted terminology has shifted in the interim, as things were added and times changed. C++ is _multi-paradigm_, supporting class-based OO as an option but alternatives too (imperative, concurrent, template metaprogramming). Java has elements of some of these things but is fundamentally OO in a way that C++ never was.

Comment: you can explicitely inherit the constructor with "`struct B : public A { using A::A; };`" see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In C++14, the [definition of aggregate](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.init.aggr) was:

> An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause [class]) with no user-provided constructors ([class.ctor]), no private or protected non-static data members (Clause [class.access]), **no base classes** (Clause [class.derived]), and no virtual functions ([class.virtual]).

Hence, `B` is not an aggregate. As a result `B{}` is surely not aggregate initialization, and `B{}` and `B()` end up meaning the same thing. They both just invoke `B`'s default constructor.

However, in C++17, the [definition of aggregate](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.aggr#1) was changed to:

> An *aggregate* is an array or a class with
>
> - no user-provided, explicit, or inherited constructors ([class.ctor]),
> - no private or protected non-static data members (Clause [class.access]),
> - no virtual functions, and
> - **no virtual, private, or protected base classes** ([class.mi]).
>
> *[ Note:* Aggregate initialization does not allow accessing protected and private base class' members or constructors.  *— end note ]*

The restriction is no longer on *any* base classes, but just on virtual/private/protected ones. But `B` has a public base class. It is now an aggregate! And C++17 aggregate initialization does allow for initializing base class subobjects.

In particular, `B{}` is aggregate initialization where we just don't provide an initializer for any subobject. But the first (and only) subobject is an `A`, which we're trying to initialize from `{}` (during aggregate initialization, any subobject without an explicit initializer is copy-initialized from `{}`), which we can't do because `A`'s constructor is protected and we are not a friend (see also, the quoted note).

---

Note that, just for fun, in C++20 the [definition of aggregate](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#1) will change again.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit What was actually confusing for most of us (I think) was how you (can) initialize aggregate with base class with `B{A{}}`, and if such initializer is missing, an "empty initializer" is added for the `A` subobject, and not one for each members of `A`, as I would have thought before.

Comment: @Holt Yep agreed

Answer (score 4):

From my understanding of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization

`B{}` does an [aggregate_initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization),

and since C++17:

> The effects of aggregate initialization are:
>
> - Each direct public base, (since C++17) [..] is copy-initialized from the corresponding clause of the initializer list.

and in our case:

> If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members and bases (since C++17) or initializer list is completely empty, the remaining members and bases (since C++17) are initialized by their default initializers, if provided in the class definition, and otherwise (since C++14) by empty lists, in accordance with the usual list-initialization rules (which performs value-initialization for non-class types and non-aggregate classes with default constructors, and aggregate initialization for aggregates). If a member of a reference type is one of these remaining members, the program is ill-formed.

So `B{/*constructor of A*/}` need to construct base class A, which is protected...

Answer (score 4):

The final draft of C++17 n4659 has a compatibility section which contains the changes with respect to previous versions.

> C.4.4 Clause 11: declarators [diff.cpp14.decl]
>
> 11.6.1
>   Change: Definition of an aggregate is extended to apply to user-defined types with base classes.
>   Rationale: To increase
>   convenience of aggregate initialization.
>   Effect on original feature:
>   Valid C++ 2014 code may fail to compile or produce different results
>   in this International Standard; initialization from an empty
>   initializer list will perform aggregate initialization instead of
>   invoking a default constructor for the affected types:
>
> ```
> struct derived;
> struct base {
> friend struct derived;
> private:
> base();
> };
> struct derived : base {};
> derived d1{}; // Error. The code was well-formed before.
> derived d2; // still OK
> ```

I compiled the above example code with `-std=c++14` and it compiled but failed to compile with `-std=c++17`.

I believe that could be the reason why the code in the OP fails with `B{}` but succeeds with `B()`.